# Sum of string with positive and negative integers

Tags: python, list, split, integer

I have a string such as "12-569-8" and want to split it into a list of negative and positive integers so I can add them together -- such as

```
list = ['1', '2', '-5', '6', '9', '-8']
```

where the sum would be 5. I'm mostly struggling with splitting the list.

Comment: Please post the code that is giving you trouble.  This is not a coding or tutorial service.  "I'm mostly struggling" is not a sufficient problem specification.

Comment: That said, either look up how to handle integers with regular expressions, or ... break the string into individual characters.  Go through that list, converting individual digits.  When you hit a minus sign, you know that the next digit has to be negated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach could be to use a regular expression, and match both digits or digits preceded by a negative sign:

```
s = "12-569-8"
import re

sum(map(int,re.findall(r'(\d|-\d)', s)))
# 5
```

The other approach, as mentioned by prune in the comments, is looping over the characters and either adding or subtracting based on what you find:

```
res = 0
i=0
while i < len(s):
    x = s[i]
    if x != '-':
        res += int(x)
    else:
        i += 1
        res -= int(s[i])
    i += 1

print(res)
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an import, you can separate all the characters with a space and remove the space after minus signs.  Then split the string on spaces and each number will be correctly interpreted:

```
s = "12-569-8"
c = " ".join(s).replace("- ","-") # space out, remove space after minus
n = list(map(int,c.split()))      # split and convert to integers 

print(c) # '1 2 -5 6 9 -8'
print(n) # [1, 2, -5, 6, 9, -8]
```